# batch processing script: image manipulating by adding logo and footer

Tags: html, css, image, batch-file

I am a newbie with scripting and are looking here for advice which language to use and ask for a first example.

I want to start a script which opens a specific folder XYZ and processes the following in a batch:

- open first image in folder (png's or tifs)
- copy image file name (!!! only the first 12 digits) and type that text as a footer on the image at position Xcm Ycm
  in Arial / size 12  / color black
- add to the image a specific logo.png from path at position Xcm Ycm.
- resize the image down to pixel 1024 to 1248
- save the image as png
- start with next image...

This script I want to use on hundreds of images with just starting it ones.
This script is just for usage on my desktop and will not implemented on websites.

Which scripting language is the best to use?
How to write the script without listing all the image filename?
How do I say that only the first 12 digits are to copy and paste as text in Arial on the image.

And finally how to start the script?

Thanks in million!

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux or what other OS?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Imagemagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

It is a command-line tool. It's command-line is comparably complex, you'll need to spend an hour or two reading documentation, but it totally worth it. It can do what you describe and much more.

Comment: Dear akhikhi, Thanks in million. I will use the Info!